# PHPMailer SERVER -> CLIENT: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay

Tags: php, exchange-server, phpmailer

I have a problem to send mail with phpmailer and microsoft exchange.

here is my code :

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'mail.myhost.com';
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->Username   = "myUsername";
$mail->Password   = "myPassword";
$mail->From = "from@server.com";
$mail->AddAddress("some.address@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = 'Test';
$mail->send();
```

and i obtain this message :

```
2014-06-04 13:34:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 SRV-******.***.local Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 4 Jun 2014 15:38:20 +0200 
2014-06-04 13:34:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO myhost.com
2014-06-04 13:34:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-SRV-******.***.local  Hello [87.254.99.10] 250-SIZE 99999744 250-PIPELINING 250-DSN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-STARTTLS 250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS 250-AUTH 250-X-EXPS NTLM 250-8BITMIME 250-BINARYMIME 250-CHUNKING 250-XEXCH50 250 XSHADOW 
2014-06-04 13:34:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 
2014-06-04 13:34:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Sender OK 
2014-06-04 13:34:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 
2014-06-04 13:34:54 SERVER -> CLIENT: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay 
2014-06-04 13:34:54 SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay 
2014-06-04 13:34:54 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2014-06-04 13:34:54 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: some.address@gmail.com
```

My "from" and "to" mail adress are missing ...

Is someone know what is the problem ?

Comment: Take a look into this: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/550+5.7.1+Unable+to+Relay+Mail+From+Exchange+Server Not sure, if it is the problem.

Comment: Thx, i think that it is the problem, i will take a look tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

First of all I reccomend for you to set *true* in

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

for the *from* field, insert it in between the brackets and change the parameter in *setFrom*

```
$mail->setFrom = ("from@server.com");
```